# how to give a panel its exact size in c#?

Tags: c#, printing, size

I'm not an English user,so forgive me for grammatical problems please. Smile | :) 
I have some paper forms that i want to print some labels on them.these papers have special size(24 cm * 14).so I made a panel(907 pixel * 529 pixel) and i put my labels on it(I converted cm to pixel and i put labels in the special parts of my panel).these labels are going to be printed in empty fields of my paper forms.but the problem is that, just the first form can be printed in the right style.others are printed in upper place of the form. I thought it may be because of I didn't give my panel and labels exact size in pixel. but i couldn't give my panel exact size in pixels,coz it doesn't accept pixels in decimal. any ideas?
this is a part of my code:

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 188, 400, 302, 400);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 330, 319, 122, 55);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(label20.Text, label20.Font, new SolidBrush(label20.ForeColor), label20.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(label21.Text, label21.Font, new SolidBrush(label21.ForeColor), label21.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(label23.Text, label23.Font, new SolidBrush(label23.ForeColor), label23.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(label24.Text, label24.Font, new SolidBrush(label24.ForeColor), label24.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(label25.Text, label25.Font, new SolidBrush(label25.ForeColor), label25.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(label26.Text, label26.Font, new SolidBrush(label26.ForeColor), label26.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(label27.Text, label27.Font, new SolidBrush(label27.ForeColor), label27.Location);
e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl_kod.Text, lbl_kod.Font, new SolidBrush(lbl_kod.ForeColor), lbl_kod.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl_ttarikh.Text, lbl_ttarikh.Font, new SolidBrush(lbl_ttarikh.ForeColor), lbl_ttarikh.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl_ctot25.Text, lbl_ctot25.Font, new SolidBrush(lbl_ctot25.ForeColor), lbl_ctot25.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl_pricetot25.Text, lbl_pricetot25.Font, new SolidBrush(lbl_pricetot25.ForeColor), lbl_pricetot25.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl_pricetot.Text, lbl_pricetot.Font, new SolidBrush(lbl_pricetot.ForeColor), lbl_pricetot.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl_pricetoth.Text, lbl_pricetoth.Font, new SolidBrush(lbl_pricetoth.ForeColor), lbl_pricetoth.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl_name.Text, lbl_name.Font, new SolidBrush(lbl_name.ForeColor), lbl_name.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl_dtarikh.Text, lbl_dtarikh.Font, new SolidBrush(lbl_dtarikh.ForeColor), lbl_dtarikh.Location);        

            }
```

and the print region for each paper form:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount && k < 3878; i++)
            {
                k = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                bool found = false;
                ctot25 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value);
                ctot50 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value);
                ctot100 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value);
                foreach (object row1 in hoome)
                    if (row1.ToString() == (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value).ToString())
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }

                if (found == false)
                {
                    if (i > 0 && ctot25 != 0 || ctot50 != 0 || ctot100 != 0)
                    {
                        #region tarikh
                        string date = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                        var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(date);
                        aStringBuilder.Insert(2, "/");
                        aStringBuilder.Insert(5, "/");
                        lbl_dtarikh.Text = aStringBuilder.ToString();

                        lbl_ttarikh.Text = datestringbuilder.ToString();
                        #endregion

                        decimal pricetot25;
                        pricetot25 = ctot25 * price25;
                        lbl_name.Text = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString();
                        lbl_kod.Text = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value).ToString();
                        lbl_ctot25.Text = (ctot25).ToString();
                        lbl_pricetot25.Text = (pricetot25).ToString();
                        lbl_pricetoth.Text = num2str(pricetot.ToString()) + " ریال" + "//";

                        #region print
                        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument doc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
                        doc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
                        PrintDialog PrintSettings = new PrintDialog();
                        PrintSettings.Document = doc;
                        PageSettings pgsetting = new PageSettings();
                        doc.Print();
                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            }
```

here is a link to my screenshot:
[my panel](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-08/55660527167028539435.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is a little unclear, I think you better not to add your panel in design layout and create it programmatically. It'd be better if u take a screenshot of your second page.

**EDIT:**

Try creating labels in your FOR loop. You can drop panel in this way. I hope it works

```
 if (found == false)
                {
                    if (i > 0 && ctot25 != 0 || ctot50 != 0 || ctot100 != 0)
                    {
                        //Somthethin

                        Label lbl_Name = new Label { Location = new Point(50, 50), Text = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString() };
                         this.Controls.Add(lbl_Name);

                         //The rest of the codes

                    }
                }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. if a create my panel programmatically can i give it a size like (907.086614173 pixel * 529.133858268 pixel)?

Comment: You can't use double digits in new size. It's gotta be like this
Panel pnl = new Panel { Size = new Size(907, 529)};

Comment: this is exactly my problem. i think the problem starts from here.in my printing process just the first panel's labels stick in their true positions on the paper and others are printed in upper positions,so i thought it must be because of I didn't give them exact position.I mean i thought the problem is because of that 0.133858268.

Comment: As you said, you're not very good in English. that's why your problem is still a little unclear to me. since Your name is a Persian, I think you can explain the problem in Persian. Are you designing a new form for every page?

Comment: yes,that' right.sorry for bothering you with my unclear question. yes. for each paper the print process starts again.because each paper has its own label fields.but the positions are the same.just the label contents are changing.

Comment: OK. I have two Questions.1-Can you take a screenshot from your second page problem? 2-Are you Persian? Cause it will be easier if you explain your problem in Persian/Farsi.

Comment: no,i can't send pictures,coz I don't have enough reputations. yes,I'm persian